# WCF Session: How to make use of sessions

Tags: c#, wcf, session

I have read some articles on WCF Sessions on code projects and MSDN, and according to this diagram that I have found:

[image]

if I do the below code, the value of `i` must keep increasing if called from the same instance, but it does not:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Test" in code, svc and config file together.
// NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Test.svc or Test.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
public class Test : ITest
{
    int i = 0;
    public int DoWork()
    {
        i++;
        return i;
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceReference1.TestClient c = new ServiceReference1.TestClient();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.DoWork(new ServiceReference1.DoWorkRequest()).DoWorkResult);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

This is while when I use the `Single`, it keeps increasing.
My question is that how can I make use of sessions to achive this in a per-session manner (not like the single) ?

Comment: Well, it really depends on *which* bindings you use - if you want sessions, you **must use** a session-capable binding, of course (like `wsHttpBinding`). If you're using a non-session-capable binding, then you won't get the benefits of the session....

Comment: @marc_s: even the `wsHttpBinding` does not work!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183865.aspx ?

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Honestly MSDN is the most useless help available!